# MySQL Database Show Lik '×¨×•×œ×¨ ×—×•×'

Tags: mysql, database, encoding

I have imported a database which includes Hebrew. The Hebrew in the database looks like this: `×§×™×¨×•×¨×™×ª ×œ 4 ×¤×—×™×•×ª ×ž×‘×™×ª ××ž×’×–×™×ª`

I tried to change the encoding to UTF-8 but it still looks the same.

How can I fix this?

If any more information needed tell me and I'll provide.

Thanks.

Comment: I think you will need to change the database encoding to UTF-8 and _also_ reimport your Hebrew data.  This is because information may have been lost/truncated when you incorrectly imported the Hebrew text the first time around, using the wrong encoding.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UTF-8 all the way through](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through)

Comment: it can be represented with `UTF-8` - so one can have Latin & Iwrith letters, at the same time (hint: you need to use `UTF-8` encoding for the script files, too).

Answer (score 0):

That's "Mojibake" for something close to `קירורית ל 4 פחיות מבית �מגזי`, correct?

See [Trouble with UTF-8 characters; what I see is not what I stored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf-8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored) for the cause, to wit:

- The bytes to be stored need to be UTF-8-encoded. Fix this.
- The connection when INSERTing and SELECTing text needs to specify utf8 or utf8mb4. Fix this.
- The column needs to be declared CHARACTER SET utf8 (or utf8mb4). Fix this.
- HTML should start with .

The appropriate fix *for the data* is here: http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/charcoll#fixes_for_various_cases

Comment: Is there a php function which converts it back to the original data?

Comment: @Omer - There may be, but I would prefer to stay in MySQL.  Look around, there are lots of questions that ask about PHP/Java/etc solutions, but many of them failed.